# Spring-boot & hibernate, using transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, transactional

I'm trying to use spring-boot and hibernate. 
It works good when I use repositories, but I'm trying to get a Hibernate session to create a DAO, and this DAO is not being part of the transaction.

This is the test code:

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UserBusiness userBusiness;

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return factory.getSessionFactory();
    }       

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        try {
            userBusiness.createAdminUsers();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(userBusiness.listAll());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();
    }
}
```

UserBusinessImpl.java:

```
@Service
public class UserBusinessImpl implements UserBusiness {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void createAdminUsers() throws Exception {
        userRepository.save(new User("User1", "u1", "123"));
        userRepository.save(new User("User2", "u2", "123"));
        userDao.test();
        throw new Exception("Rollback");
    }

    public List<User> listAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

UserDao:

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void teste() {
        //current session does not exists and throws org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
//        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(new User("testDao", "dao", "123"));
        sessionFactory.openSession().save(new User("testDao", "dao", "123"));
    }
}
```

When I try to getCurrentSession() it throws me an error. 
and the openSession() is detached from my transaction so when Business throws and exception the Dao save is not rolled back. The two other inserts are rolled back.

How would be the correct way to get the currentSession in the DAO?

UPDATE: 
If I do a sessionFactory.openSession() it does not give any exception, but it's not part of the transaction.

If I try to use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() that's the stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
2014-09-26 11:00:28.488 TRACE 20938 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@ff80080] for key [public abstract java.util.List org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.findAll()] to thread [main]
2014-09-26 11:00:28.488 DEBUG 20938 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
2014-09-26 11:00:28.489 DEBUG 20938 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@62e8dbb0] for JPA transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1010)
    at org.sparta.hibernatetest.UserDao.teste(UserDao.java:35)
    at org.sparta.hibernatetest.business.UserBusinessImpl.createAdminUsers(UserBusinessImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.createAdminUsers(Unknown Source)
    at org.sparta.hibernatetest.Application.run(Application.java:33)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:677)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:695)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.sparta.hibernatetest.Application.main(Application.java:42)
```

Comment: What exceptions you are getting, post the complete stacktrace

Comment: `getCurrentSession()` will only work ni the boundary of a transaction without it it won't work. So basically make your method part of the transaction. But I wonder why you already have a repository that can do a save it uses JPA so why do you even need a plain `SessionFactory`.

Comment: I don't need to do the save using the DAO. I put the save in the DAO more as of an example. But what I want is to be able to write my DAOs that will access Hibernate directly, making me able to write my own Criterias, and this being managed by @Transactional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager entityManager;

   protected Session getCurrentSession()  {
      return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
   }

   public void test() {
      Session session = getCurrentSession();
      session().save(new User("testDao", "dao", "123"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
entityManager.persist(new User("testDao", "dao", "123"))
```

(and other EntityManager methods) instead of using Hibernate Session directly.